# Find most recent Status for each Employee, based on annual updates

Tags: sql

I have a problem with a query.

I have one table named EMPLOYEE and there i have the fields NAME, YEAR and STATUS.

Every employee can have several years and several status but I need the status of the most recent year.

How can I get that data?

Comment: What rdbms are you using? What have you achieved so far?

Comment: I've tried to edit the title. It may not be entirely correct, so please feel free to edit. But DON'T SHOUT.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should do it:

```
SELECT e.[Name],
       e.[Year],
       e.[Status]
FROM employee AS e
     INNER JOIN
(
    SELECT [Name],
           MAX([Year])
    FROM employee
    GROUP BY [Name]
) AS m ON e.[Name] = m.[Name]
          AND e.[Year] = m.[Year];
```